# View flickers on Android

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, rhomobile

I am developing an android application using Rhodes.

The transition between view works perfect on iPhone, but on android it flickers.

Please help

Answer (score 4):

This is answer is probably not going to be the most satisfying in the world, but... There is nothing you can do to affect this short of turning off page transitions.  Sometimes, even the iPhone can flicker between transitions.  This has something to do with the transition system in jQuery Mobile. On an iPhone, transitions are smooth and you don't always see the flicker.  Android is not written in the same way as iOS so it handles animations and transitions a little less gracefully and this can cause choppy transitions and blinking in the between pages.

Some of the newest androids are starting to better deal with this. I've tested on a Samsung Galaxy S2 and thanks to it's fast dual core processors, the transitions are almost as smooth and flickerless as an old iPhone 3G.

In the mean time, until Android catches up, it may be better to just turn page transitions off.  It makes the system feel faster anyway and fast is a billable feature. :-)

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.defaultPageTransition="none";
});
```